# how to get title of the containing Jquery dialog?

Tags: jquery

I need to send the title of the jquery dialog to the server, Is it possible to retrieve it without traversing the DOM and finding the?

I know that (`<span class="ui-dialog-title"></span>`) can be retrieved using jQuery but I wanted to know if there is a better way.

```
 $(c[0]).html(html).dialog({
                title: "Brief Country List",
                resizable: false,
                draggable: false,
                width: 900,
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: true,
                buttons: {
                    Done: function () {
                        Neptune.BriefCountrySection.SaveCountry();
                    },
                    Export: function () {

                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: '/Briefs/ExportCsv',
                            data: /*Get the title here*/,
                            dataType: 'JSON',
                            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                            success: function (res) {
                                if (res.Success) {
                                    var item = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.Countries(), function (i) {
                                        return i.ListID() == self.SelectedCountryListID();
                                    });

                                    if (item != null) {
                                        self.Countries.remove(item);
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    Neptune.ShowAlert({ content: res.FriendlyErrorMessage });
                                }
                            },
                            error: function (jqXHR, status, err) {
                                Neptune.ShowAlert({ content: status });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get that by calling

```
var title = $( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "title" );
```

See http://api.jqueryui.com/1.9/dialog/#option-title

These options are contained in data of dom element

```
$("div#dialog").data("uiDialog").options.title
```

I don't reccomend using this second way as it may be dependent on jQuery version and change in the future, it is just illustration how it works.

Of course, adjust your selector to select proper dialog, if you are calling this ajax from dialog button, then it should be `$(this)`